# Percona Audit Log plugin not auditing account

Tags: audit, percona-server

I have setup the Percona-server-5.6.41-89 Audit plugin with the following settings:

```
audit_log_policy=QUERIES
audit_log_handler=FILE
audit_log_file=/var/log/mysql/perc_audit.txt
audit_log_format=CSV
audit_log_rotate_on_size=1000000000
audit_log_rotations=9
audit_log_include_accounts=someuser@%
```

Now for some reason, auditing is not being performed against the configured account. I tried `SET GLOBAL audit_log_include_accounts="'someuser'@'%'";`, but with no success.

How do I need to set up the `audit_log_include_accounts` parameter so that it contains wildcards in the host part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution is `SET GLOBAL audit_log_include_accounts='someuser@';` - without host part of definition, BUT with `@`